# ASP.NET Core и JSON-RPC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, json-rpc

Я создал проект с поддержкой WebAPI и в общем классический REST работает отлично, но также мне нужна поддержка JSON-RPC. Я видел штуки вроде [этой](https://github.com/alexanderkozlenko/aspnetcore-json-rpc) и [этой](https://github.com/edjCase/JsonRpc), но не знаю что именно выбрать.
Получается, что два aspnetcore приложения должны уметь между собой общаться именно через JSON-RPC в рамках HTTP.

Как такое принято делать?

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Спасибо, обновил.

Comment: Если у вас нет чётких требований - делайте любым образом. Судя по вопросу у вас их нет в голове. Ну так и набирайте опыт, когда набьете шишек или появится понимание, что именно нужно - тогда вернётесь ещё раз, с новым, уточнённым вопросом.

Comment: Никто не мешает самому писать сердес и обвязку ко всему, но у меня не так много свободного времени, потому и спрашиваю про типовые и отработанные решения.

Comment: Вот [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/441854/) буквально на днях пролетала - посмотрите профили тех, кто отписывался и напишите в личку тем, кто пишет на c# спросите, может кто подскажет свой любимый вариант. Можете также и ссылку на этот вопрос дать, чтобы потом и другим пригодилось.